# MonoTouch/MonoDroid - Translate Raw touch coordinates to screen coordinates

Tags: c#, touch, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

What's the proper way to translate raw touch points to screen coordinates in MonoTouch or MonoDroid?  My code works well on the emulator but the points are inaccurate on a device.  Here's what I have so far:

```
    private void Initialize()
    {
        this.Touch += TouchView_Touch;
    }

    void TouchView_Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ReturnValue = true;
        touchPoints.Add(e.Event.RawX);
        touchPoints.Add(e.Event.RawY);
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
        canvas.DrawColor(Color.White);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.Color = Color.Black;

        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        canvas.GetMatrix(m);
        float[] destination = touchPoints.ToArray();

        Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
        bool canInvert = m.Invert(inverse);
        inverse.MapPoints(destination);

        canvas.DrawPoints(destination, p);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MonoDroid, there are several StackOverflow Android questions which address the same topic, e.g.:

> [How to get the absolute coordinates of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view)

which suggests using [`View.GetLocationOnScreen(int[])`](http://docs.monodroid.net/index.aspx?link=M:Android.Views.View.GetLocationOnScreen(System.Int32[])) or [`View.GetLocationInWindow()`](http://docs.monodroid.net/index.aspx?link=M:Android.Views.View.GetLocationInWindow(System.Int32[])).

There is also

> [mismatch of event coordinates and view coordinates in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152097/mismatch-of-event-coordinates-and-view-coordinates-in-android)

which also suggests using `View.GetLocationOnScreen()` along with getting the screen metrics for the default display.

Answer (score 0):

For Monotouch you can use ConvertPointToView which is part of all UIViews. It will convert the point to the correct coordinate for the view you pass in.