# MonoDroid SurfaceView

Tags: c#, android, mono, drawable, xamarin.android

I am finding very little information on the subject for Mono.  I need a drawable area with which to capture signatures. Been trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618405/monotouch-monodroid-translate-raw-touch-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates), but am a little lost.  Not sure whether my class is to extend SurfaceView or just create a SurfaceView in OnCreate. The touch event handler uses e.ReturnValue and touchPoints, and View.TouchEventArgs e doesn't have a definition for ReturnValue nor do I have any idea where touchPoints is coming from.

Comment: Does the lack of response mean this is impossible?  I know it is possible in Android, is the problem that we are in Mono?

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this in Java Android?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html

Comment: I don't see any e.ReturnValues/TouchEventArgs in the sample you linked to but here's a direct port of it to Mono for Android if this is useful: https://gist.github.com/e5642f4fb912c7d5b576

Comment: e.ReturnValues/TouchEventArgs is found in the example I provided in the original question.  It is supposed to be an actual Mono example.

Answer (score 0):

To help answer this question, I have ported over this TouchPaint example: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html (the link uses a ICS example but you could probably change it so it works on older versons). The port can be found here https://gist.github.com/e5642f4fb912c7d5b576

The example is heavily based around having a trackball which most devices don't have, click on the trackball would change the color but to help show that changing the colour does work, OnDraw will use a different color each time.