# get the coordinates(x and y) of currently visible part in the screen of that bit map

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, zooming

I need to know;

When a bitmap image is zoomed how to get the coordinates(x and y) of currently visible part in the screen of that bit map

Thanks

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933612/how-to-convert-coordinates-of-the-image-view-to-the-coordinates-of-the-bitmap/4934840#4934840) was linked to through [an answer you already got](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12331714/1438733). You need to show some research effort or you're going to get very little help.

Comment: but @Eric it that answer didn't help me at all so now i tries to get the coordinates of the four corners of bitmap part which displays after zooming
thank

Answer (score 0):

```
float [] values = new float[9];
matrix.getValues(values);
```

the x coor you want --> `float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];`

the y coor you want --> `float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];`