# How can I get the coordinates and size of ImageView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

When I click the button，call drawDigit()，puzzleview is only a LinearLayout in Activity

```
protected void drawDigit(Canvas canvas, int digit) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(num < diff){
            int x = tiles.get(num).getScrollX();  // get the X coordinate of ImageView，it's 0
            int y = tiles.get(num).getScrollY();  // get the Y coordinate of ImageView，it's 0
            float height = tiles.get(num).getHeight(); // height is 0
            float width = tiles.get(num).getWidth();   // width is 0
            background.setTextSize(height * 0.75f);
            background.setStyle(Style.FILL);
            background.setTextScaleX(width/height);
            background.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            canvas.drawText(digit + "", x, y, background);
            //num++;
        }
    }
```

How can I assign the `ImageView` in Layout to tiles,then get the coordinate and size?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933612/how-to-convert-coordinates-of-the-image-view-to-the-coordinates-of-the-bitmap. Have a look at the answer in the link , Should help you.

Comment: What's `num`? What's `diff`? What's `tiles`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

**//This is for Getting ImageView size that is fixed in layout**

```
int imageHeight;
int imageWidth;

ImageView imageViewObj = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_id);
ViewTreeObserver treeObsObj = imageViewObj.getViewTreeObserver();
treeObsObj.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

    public boolean onPreDraw() {
    imageWidth= imageViewObj.getMeasuredWidth();
    imageHeight = imageViewObj.getMeasuredHeight();
    return true;
}
});
```

**// Getting the size of the Image inside the ImageView and The size will differ based

  **// on the image you placed inside the ImageView**

```
ImageView imageObj = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view_id);
int imageWidth = imageObj.getWidth();
int imageHeight = imageObj.getHeight();
```

Comment: ya,but the result is not right. it is not 0, the first is 120, and the second is 60.  the second method is 0. how to calculate the coordinate?