# Getting the Bitmap coordinates contained in a View (Android)

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have a modified <del>ImageView</del> View that has as a parameter a BitMap. I want to get the x,y coordinates  from the Bitmap when the “onTouch” from the <del>ImageView</del> View  is fired in order to plot a point. So far I am able to get the x,y coordinates from the <del>ImageView</del> View and draw a point. The problem is that when I move or resize the image the drawn points wont reference the same position on the BitMap.

Does anyone know how to get the x, y coordinates from a bitmap inside a <del>ImageView</del>  View?

Note 1: the original size of the image is bigger than the resolution of the screen

[image: initial dots]
[image: [resized image]
[image: resized an moved]

Comment: you should probably see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933612/how-to-convert-coordinates-of-the-image-view-to-the-coordinates-of-the-bitmap).

Comment: I tried to use the question that you point out, but that didn't work. I am using a class that inherits from View and implements onTouchListener. I define a bitmap atribute and that is the image that I drawn in the onDraw(). I use Matrix in order to zoom in or zoom out and move the image arround -canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint)-. My problem is that I can't  get the scaledHeight and scaledWidth. I queep a value that represent the scaled size, so i tried to do something like: x=ldm.getX()*scale;
   y=ldm.getY()*scale;
   ldm.setX(x);
   ldm.setY(y); but it didnt work