# Get real x and y coordinates of users touch

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, ontouchlistener

I need to map onTouch event's X, Y coordinates to the Bitmap X, Y coordinates inside the ImageView to do this I use the following approach.

However this approach seems to only work when I either:
a) Fully zoom the image (all the way in)
b) Works in any case if I make my application full screen

```
  final int index = event.getActionIndex();
  touchLocation = new float[] {
    event.getX(index), event.getY(index)
  };

  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
  ImageView view = getImageView();
  view.getImageMatrix().invert(matrix);

  matrix.postTranslate(view.getScrollX(), view.getScrollY());
  matrix.mapPoints(touchLocation);
  // touchLocation[0] is real x and [1] is real y
```

However my activity is an ActionBar activity so at I get a bit wrong position on the Y axis. I tried deducting the height of ActionBar and StatusBar but this does not always work.

What is odd is that on full screen it does not matter if I fully zoom my image in or out I always get correct coordinates calculated however with any other Activity type this will not map points correctly.

Comment: where are your receiving the event from? is the event coming from a touch event from a parent of the image view, or from the image view itself?

Comment: I think you should refer to this link:
[How to get actionbar height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301510/how-to-get-the-actionbar-height). It will help to compute the correct touch X and Y coordinate. I've encountered this problem too.

Comment: So you're starting with the absolute coordinates on screen and need to convert to coordinates relative to the top-left of the image?

Comment: @GilMoshayof event is received from the onTouch listener.

Comment: @Joey Does not map points correctly it seems the coordinates are bound to ImageView which fills up the entire layout starts right bellow ActionBar.

Comment: Sorry man. I've searched previous question and I found this [How to convert coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933612/how-to-convert-coordinates-of-the-image-view-to-the-coordinates-of-the-bitmap). Hope this will help you now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this code to get the actually axis of touch on screen:

```
PointF p = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
View v = this;// your view
View root = v.getRootView();
while (v.getParent() instanceof View && v.getParent() != root) {
  p.y += v.getTop();
  p.x += v.getLeft();
  v = (View) v.getParent();
}
```

Hope this works for you as well

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell from the pasted code what the exact problem is, but it looks like you should use: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[]) and take that into account for your calculation.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your Actionbar and status heights are in pixel and not dp
and also you can try using getRawX() and getRawY() instead of getX(), getY()

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
int[] viewCoords = new int[2];
imageView.getLocationOnScreen(viewCoords);
int touchX = (int) event.getX();
int touchY = (int) event.getY();

int imageX = touchX - viewCoords[0]; // viewCoords[0] is the X coordinate
int imageY = touchY - viewCoords[1]; // viewCoords[1] is the y coordinate
```

you will get the x and y coordinates using this way

Answer (score 2):

Override onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) and then call event.getX() and event.getY() to get the coordinate positions of where the user touched [they will be floats].  ( by : @antonyt )

Comment: Not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 : Create one custom CustomFrameLayout extending `FrameLayout` in your app that can take one interface object in constructor. (interface will be created in step 3)

Step 2 : Write/Override `onInterceptTouchEvent` method.

Step 3 : Make one interface to send/receive desired params.

Step 4 : Implement interface and method created in step 3 in your activity/fragment

Step 5 : In your activity/fragment create object of `CustomFrameLayout` with implement interface.

Step 6 : In custom layout's overridden method, pass value to activity through the interface

Hope this will work!

---

Making a demo would take a bit longer, would have rather post as comment but still posting as answer so that I can someday improve with some example code.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps me get proper coordinates.