# How to take real coordinates(X,Y) of Bitmap from imageView Android

Tags: android, bitmap, xamarin, imageview, coordinates

i have little problem.
I'm getting an image,converting to **Bitmap** and fill imageview with this **Bitmap**.

So the problem is,how to take real coordinates(X,Y) of this Bitmap?
For better illustration, i attached an image:
[image: What i have]
As shown on picture, for e.g. i got an image with Custom Resolution,where user can make an ***perspective*** , via yellow points.
So i need to know,how to take real coords of bitmap from ImageView.

What i've made at current moment(but this approach isn't correct):
i take **width**/**height** from imageView and recreating new bitmap with this resolution.

```
Bitmap bt = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Activity.Resources, Resource.Drawable.test),800,1420,false); //800 width 1420 height
                imgView.SetImageBitmap(bt);
```

Via implementation of **TouchListener**(methods **GetX()**/**GetY()**),i get coords of points(yellow circle's that overlayed on Bitmap), and the problem is that these coordinates not correct.

Also its interesting for me case when i'm stretching bitmap via ScaleType.FitXY on imageView(its possible to take real coords of bitmap) ?

So how can i achieve my goal?

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933612/how-to-convert-coordinates-of-the-image-view-to-the-coordinates-of-the-bitmap)?

Comment: @Poger yes,i'm trying now to implement. Do you have anothers ideas? :)

Comment: see getImageMatrix and read Matrix docs

Comment: @Poger for some reason(dont know why),i got same values on intrinsicHeight/Width and ScaledHeight/Width

Comment: @pskink Okay,ill do. thanks

Comment: @VetaLio dont use accepted answer from that link, use the answer with `Matrix` (the second one, by `akonsu`)

Comment: @pskink i tried also,same coords as simple GetX() :(

Comment: see [this](http://pastebin.com/MvBTTRpu)

Comment: @pskink seems that your are right(coords that i see in logs(w/ inverse of matrix) and coords that i get w/o invert matrix are different). But strange why my perspective doesnt work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `ImageView#getImageMatrix`, something like this:

```
    final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    setContentView(iv);
    // setup your image here by 
    // calling for example iv.setImageBitmap()
    // or iv.setImageDrawable()
    // or iv.setImageResource()
    View.OnTouchListener otl = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            iv.getImageMatrix().invert(inverse);
            float[] pts = {
                    event.getX(), event.getY()
            };
            inverse.mapPoints(pts);
            Log.d(TAG, "onTouch x: " + Math.floor(pts[0]) + ", y: " + Math.floor(pts[1]));
            return false;
        }
    };
    iv.setOnTouchListener(otl);
```