# How to find out the coordinate of an image in relative layout

Tags: android, image, dictionary, coordinate-systems

I want to do an app related in indoor map.  Now, I knows the the coordinate but how can I place them into app without distorting layout under different screen sizes.

1. Is it possible to have coordinates under relative view?
2. Should I place my own map as background under frame layout? (map isn't in scroll view)
3. Is is possible to have my own custom coordination instead of relay on the screen's coordinate? By this mean I meant I can cut down the map in my own max x and y.
4. I tried to find out how an image moves as I throw the x and y and it can change position on it's own in every second.

   Please help me out and give me some ideas that will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Depending on size of image which you'd like to use as a map different solutions are possible. I'd suggest to use [TileView](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView) for large images or if your app needs to be scalable to larger images. If what you need is just a mapping of one image take a look on this answer:
[How to convert coordinates of the image view to the coordinates of the bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933612/how-to-convert-coordinates-of-the-image-view-to-the-coordinates-of-the-bitmap) 
Sure you can even write your own scalable solution based on it.