# How do I correctly translate pixel coordinates to canvas coordinates in Android?

Tags: android, events, pixel, android-canvas

I am capturing a `MotionEvent` for a long click in an Android `SurfaceView` using a `GestureListener`. I then need to translate the coordinates of the `MotionEvent` to canvas coordinates, from which I can generate custom map coordinates (not Google Maps).

From what I have read, I take that given `MotionEvent e`, `e.getX()` and `e.getY()` get pixel coordinates. How can I convert these coordinates to the `SurfaceView`'s canvas coordinates?

Here is my `GestureListener` for listening for long clicks:

```
/**
* Overrides touch gestures not handled by the default touch listener
*/
private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

  @Override
  public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
     Point p = new Point();
     p.x =  (int) e.getX();
     p.y = (int) e.getY();
     //TODO translate p to canvas coordinates
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
Does this have to do with screen size/resolution/depth and the canvas' Rect object?

Comment: Did you tried `translate (float dx, float dy)`?

Comment: I looked into it. Unfortunately, I'm not drawing to the canvas. I need the actual coordinates. Once I get the canvas coordinates I plan to translate my canvas coordinates to the application's map coordinates which will be used for navigation.

Comment: Really no one else? Does this have to do with screen size/resolution/depth and the canvas' Rect object? Hasn't anyone done this translation before?

Comment: solved? I also face the same problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3152172/755804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you have a canvas View inside surfaceview. If so
try `VIEW.getLeft() | getTop()` that returns the left | top position of the view relative to it's parent.

```
float x= e.getX() - canvasView.getLeft();
float y= e.getY() - canvasView.getTop();
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried it out and it still doesn't work.

Comment: What to do when the canvas is scaled?

Answer (score 8):

You might try using the `MotionEvent.getRawX()/getRawY()` methods instead of the `getX()/getY()`.

```
// get the surfaceView's location on screen
int[] loc = new int[2];
surfaceView.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
// calculate delta
int left = e.getRawX()-loc[0];
int top = e.getRawY()-loc[1];
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you have the screen px from the display in x,y, and you can call the canvas px via:

```
Canvas c = new Canvas();
int cx = c.getWidth();
int cy = c.getHeight();
...
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int sx = display.getWidth();
int sy = display.getHeight();
```

Then, you can do the math to map the screen touch view , with the given px in both the view and the screen.

```
canvasCoordX = p.x*((float)cx/(float)sx);
canvasCoordY = p.y*((float)cy/(float)sy);
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html for more info on the screen manager.  I think it needs to be initialized inside an activity to work.

Comment: thanks for the idea. I tried it out, but it still does not work correctly.

Comment: There's no error. It does provide some translation, however it is not the correct translation. It is finding canvas coordinates way to the top of the screen no matter where I press.

Comment: I'd recommend some debugging then - it could be that the display px didn't get initialized correctly and are both 0,0.  Print out the variables, and if everything still looks good, abandon this method. :)

Answer (score 4):

I recently came upon this problem while doing something very similiar and after some trial and error and lots of googling I ended up adapting this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9945896/1131180) :

(e is a MotionEvent, so the best place to use this code would be in onTouch or onLongPress)

```
mClickCoords = new float[2];

//e is the motionevent that contains the screen touch we
//want to translate into a canvas coordinate
mClickCoords[0] = e.getX();
mClickCoords[1] = e.getY();

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.set(getMatrix());

//this is where you apply any translations/scaling/rotation etc.
//Typically you want to apply the same adjustments that you apply
//in your onDraw().

matrix.preTranslate(mVirtualX, mVirtualY);
matrix.preScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mPivotX, mPivotY);

// invert the matrix, creating the mapping from screen 
//coordinates to canvas coordinates
matrix.invert(matrix); 

//apply the mapping
matrix.mapPoints(mClickCoords);

//mClickCoords[0] is the canvas x coordinate and
//mClickCoords[1] is the y coordinate.
```

There are some obvious optimizations that can be applied here but I think it is more clear this way.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using scrolling, then the actual y on the canvas is

```
float y = event.getY() + arg0.getScrollY();
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do in these situations is just:

1. put a listener on whatever View/ViewGroup whose coordinates you wanna get by click
2. Make it store them locally
3. Whoever wants to access them should just request them via helper method.

And translation is done...