# Android app and the use of the camera

Tags: android, android-camera

Currently I'm developing an Android App for blind people that uses the device's camera.

The app shows in a SurfaceView the preview of the camera's captured frames. When the screen is touched, the app gets the coordinates from the screen, with `event.getX()` and `event.getY()`. However, what I really want to do is to obtain the coordinates of the touched point but taking as a reference the coordinates of the frame.

With `view.getLocationonScreen()` or `view.getLocationInWindow()` I can get the location of referred to the top left position where SurfaceView begins, but the frame don't occupies all the surface of the SurfaceView.

How can I transform the coordinates of the screen to relative coordinates to the frame? Or how can I know the coordinates where the frame is located inside the Surface View? When I use `getMarginLeft()` or similar I obtain the value 0.

Comment: You have to convert firstly `pixel coordinates` to `canvas coordinates`. Check [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852822/how-do-i-correctly-translate-pixel-coordinates-to-canvas-coordinates-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I can see that the canvas coordenates are obtained like:

`Canvas c = new Canvas();
int cx = c.getWidth();
int cy = c.getHeight(); `

However, I don't know how `c` is initialised.

Also, I have the problem that the video frame leaves black borders at the sides of the image inside the `SurfaceView`. I would need to adjust the frame in order to fill the whole `SurfaceView` and then use canvas over a `SurfaceView`, or remove that borders somehow.